# jquery mobile login parse json response in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

We need JSON response

> http:/host/MyService/MyService.svc/GetAuthenticatedUserData/Himansu/hits@123

when I hit the above URL in the browser, I got a response like this

```
{"GetAuthenticatedUserDataResult":1}
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass the two values (Himansu/hits@123) through code?

We tried like this:

```
var user = "Himansu";
var pw = "hits@123";
var authToken = null;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.3.136/MyService/MyService.svc/GetAuthenticatedUserData/',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "Name" : user, "Password" : pw}),
    success: function(data)
    {
    alert("goodDay");
    } 
 });
```

but no luck.

Comment: try to add this line  dataType:"json"

Comment: @kathir i got this error :- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.3.136/MyService/MyService.svc/GetAuthenticatedUserData/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: @kathir do u know any thing about my problem plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Base on your question and comments, you need to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on your back end side / web service.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS